# Optimization, descent direction, neccessary condition

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, descent

I'm learning about nonlinear, unconstrained optimization.

In my book it says that a descent direction $p_k$ must satisfy:
$$p_k\nabla f(x_k)^T < 0$$
This seems to mean that $p_k$ must be obtuse to the gradient. Why is that?

I read in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_direction) that "The motivation for such an approach is that small steps $p_k$ along  guarantee that $f$ is reduced, by Taylor's theorem." 
But I still can't see why. Is there any easy answer or intutive way to see why this is a condition or is this something that you have to do a long derivation to understand?